# Google sheet formula to swap names

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have this:

[image]

Image shows that those 2 cells contain input from another sheet.

Now, I want to input formula in those same cells that will rename inputs:

```
=if(D5="jerry.berry", "Berry Jerry", if(D5="perkins.aaron", "Aaron Perkins"))
```

**Question:** How do I insert the above formula next to `=Source!H5`

*Note: I know I can modify those values on the root sheet itself, but I would rather not.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you need:

[image]

Although I'd use a generic formula to manipulate (any) names in this string format.

Comment: there are 2 separate questions... this second one maybe is more interesting, I think it would be clearer to ask and answer in a different question

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(REGEXREPLACE(Source!H5:H6, "(.+)\.(.+)", "$2 $1")))
```

[image: 0]